# How to parse XML to return a Map from it?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I want to parse XML which looks like below:

```
<ROOT>
   <ECHO>
        <column1>NAME</column1>
        <column2>LN</column2>
        <column3>CD</column3>
        <column4>DATA0</column4>
        <column5>DATA1</column5>
        <column6>DATA2</column6>
        <column7>DATA3</column7>
   </ECHO>
   <ECHO1>
        <column1>NAME</column1>
        <column2>LN</column2>
        <column3>CD</column3>
        <column4>DATA0</column4>
   </ECHO1>
</ROOT>
```

Here I want a `Map` to be returned and somehow the key should be a nd with respect to that all the other children should be there stored in a list
To be precise it should be something like this `<key=echo ,List=ln ,cd,data0,data1,data2,data3>`.

I tried exploring JAXB but I think that would not help in my case as the name of children is not same for each case so I cannot define static number of fields in any model and unmarshal the XML to model. I want to minimize the coding effort so *SAX and DOM* parser is never on my radar. Can anyone give any clue to do this without much coding?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using a structured schema for your XML?

Comment: @Beggs I edited my question Please look in  to it previous was my mistake that i overlooked some description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Beggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1953261/beggs) basically asked if you have control over the XML format, that is, can it be slightly modified? You haven't answered that question.

Let's say that it can. The following is a slightly altered version of your original XML:

```
<ROOT>
    <data name="ECHO">
        <column>NAME</column>
        <column>LN</column>
        <column>CD</column>
        <column>DATA0</column>
        <column>DATA1</column>
        <column>DATA2</column>
        <column>DATA3</column>
    </data>
    <data name="ECHO1">
        <column>NAME</column>
        <column>LN</column>
        <column>CD</column>
        <column>DATA0</column>
    </data>
</ROOT>
```

This can easily be parsed with JAXB. Create a class for the root of the document, I will call it `Root`. Create a class for the data element, I will call it `Data`.

Class Root:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="ROOT")
public class Root {
    @XmlElement
    public List<Data> data;
}
```

Class Data:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Data {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String name;
    @XmlElement
    public List<String> column;
}
```

And then a class with a main function that will load the XML file from a file called `test.xml` in the current directory. The data will then be transferred to a `Map` and the Map is printed to show its content.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
        Unmarshaller um = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
        Root root = (Root) um.unmarshal(new File("test.xml"));
        // XML is now loaded. Turn it into a Map
        Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        for (Data data : root.data) {
            map.put(data.name, data.column);
        }
        System.out.println(map);    // Easily show content
    }
}
```

If you can't control the format of the XML data, this solution will not work.

Comment: That's beautiful, now I feel embarrassed for even suggesting resorting to a pull parser...

Comment: @JHH: Well, my answer will not work without changes to the XML format, your answer probably will.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson Thanks Yes i can change the xml format.Your answer helped me to find a way .Now i am using emf code to prase the xml.Thanks.I am accepting the answer .

Answer (score 1):

While I do think the question is a bit strange, and I agree that rethinking the problem in a way such that SAX or DOM can be used is probably wise, you might be able to use a simple XmlPullParser to accomplish this.

Assuming that your XML is always structured according to your example w.r.t the depth of keys, values etc, and assuming that your desired output is a `Map<String, List<String>>`, you might be able to do something like:

```
    int eventType;
    String key = null;
    List<String> value = null;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    while ((eventType = xpp.getEventType()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if (xpp.getDepth() == 2) {
                    key = xpp.getName();
                    value = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                if (xpp.getDepth() == 3) {
                    value.add(xpp.getText());
                }
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (xpp.getDepth() == 2) {
                    map.put(key, value);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to minimize the coding effort so SAX and DOM parser is never on my radar.

I think that you need to recalibrate your radar :-)  I suspect that SAX or DOM or similar will be the simplest way to do this.

XML bindings rely on an XML schema of some kind to give them traction.  It doesn't look like a schema is possible for your XML.

For what it is worth, you can probably code a DOM-based extractor for this use-case in 50 to 100 lines of Java code.  That's not a huge coding effort, and probably less effort than scouring the internet for alternatives.